# Expiration date and membership query

Tags: php, sql

What is wrong with this update expiration and membership?

```
      $unit = "Days";
      $length = "1";
      $newExpire = strtotime("+{$length} {$unit}");
      $sqlz  = "UPDATE users SET expire ='$newExpire' WHERE username ='{$_POST['custom']}'";
      $sql  = "UPDATE users SET membership ='14' WHERE username ='{$_POST['custom']}'";
      $retval = mysql_query( $sqlz, $sql, $conn );
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` extensions anymore. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: What is the point???Do u have any errors pls post it

Answer (score 2):

your [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)  parameter is wrong, multiple queries are not supported so, change

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sqlz, $sql, $conn );
```

to

```
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn );
```

you need to run `mysql_query` for each query individually